# How to do alerting for scheduled jobs?

Tags: prometheus, promql

We have an alert on a Kafka message lag and generally the throughput of this message stays really low. But on the last date of the month, it's supposed to be high. I want to set up correct alerting for this case.

- If it's not the last day of the month, the alert threshold can be low.
- If it's a last day of the month, the alert threshold needs to be higher, because high throughput is expected.

The current query is similar to this:

```
avg by (topic_name) (message_received_delay_histogram_all_p95_value{actor!="", environment="production", application="foo"}) > 25000.000000
```

On the last day of the month, the lag can be around 500K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `and day_of_month() != bool days_in_month()` to evaluate alert on all days except last day of the month. And using `or` add your changed alert expression for last day of the month.

Your alert expression would be something like this:

```
(avg by (topic_name) (message_received_delay_histogram_all_p95_value{actor!="", environment="production", application="foo"}) > 25000.0
  and on() day_of_month() != days_in_month())
or
(avg by (topic_name) (message_received_delay_histogram_all_p95_value{actor!="", environment="production", application="foo"}) > 500000.0
  and on() day_of_month() == days_in_month())
```

This part `and on() day_of_month() == days_in_month()` is optional and was added for better understanding.

But for visibility and readability sake I advise you to split two parts of `or` expression into two separate alerts.

EDIT: some additional useful limitations in time:

Same, but for the first day of the month

```
 and on() day_of_month() != 1)
```

Stop alert from being generated on first day of every month between 09:00 and 18:00

```
 unless on () (day_of_month() == 1 and hour()>=9 <18)
```

Comment: Thanks, what if it is start of the month instead of end of the month? is there a way that we can separate it just for few hours for more accuracy? like 1st April between 12AM to 4AM? should've asked this in the question itself

Comment: @Pratik, added to answer. For your hours (if I understood AM part correctly) you can simplify second part to `hour() <4`

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'd need, thank you! I'll try it out tomorrow and accept this answer